# No module named 'speech_recognition' in Python

Tags: python, speech-recognition

I downloaded the module 'SpeechRecognition' in my Python project. But somehow I am unable to import it in my file. Here is the code:

```
import pyttsx3
import datetime
import speech_recognition as sr
import wikipedia
import webbrowser
import random
import linecache
import pygame
import os

# Variables

# notes and game variables
notesLIST = []
turns = 0
playerscore = 0
botscore = 0

# Sapi5 is a speech recognition api
# It will be used for voice of our assistant
engine = pyttsx3.init('sapi5')

# Our assistant's voices are stored in this variable
voices = engine.getProperty('voices')
# Setting the voices
# We are getting the first voice
engine.setProperty('voices', voices[1].id)


# Functions

# Making our assistant say something
def speak(audio):
    engine.say(audio)
    engine.runAndWait()


def intro():
    """
    This functions will run when the program starts, it'll wish us and then ask us for a command
    """

    curHour = int(datetime.datetime.now().hour)
    if curHour >= 0 and curHour < 12:
        speak("Hi Sir, Good Morning.")
        print("Hi Sir, Good Morning.")
    elif curHour >= 12 and curHour < 16:
        speak("Hi Sir, Good Afternoon.")
        print("Hi Sir, Good Afternoon.")
    else:
        speak("Hi Sir, Good Evening.")
        print("Hi Sir, Good Evening.")

    print("My name is P.A.L, I am a Virtual Assistant. How may I help you?")
    speak("My name is Pal and I am a Virtual Assistant. How may I help you?")


def userCommand():
    """
    This program is used to convert user's speech to text
    """
    speech = sr.Recognizer()
    with sr.Microphone() as source:
        print("Speak now...")
        # This describes how loudly you have to say, preferred in places with loud background noise
        speech.energy_threshold = 600
        audio = speech.listen(source)

    try:
        speak("Interpreting...")
        # This stores the string value of our speech
        command = speech.recognize_google(audio, language='en-in')
        print("Your Command: ", command)

    except Exception as e:
        print("Please say that again...")
        return ""
    return command


if __name__ == '__main__':
    intro()

    # Infinite Loop
    while True:
        # Turning into lowercase string
        command = userCommand().lower()
        # Main Logic for execution of command

        if 'wikipedia' in command:
            speak("Searching Wikipedia...")
            # Replacing wikipedia string in command with blank
            command = command.replace("wikipedia", "")
            # Getting results from wikipedia
            wikiResult = wikipedia.summary(command, sentences=2)
            print(wikiResult)
            speak("The results from wikipedia show that")
            speak(wikiResult)

        elif 'what can you do' in command:
            speak("Sir, I can open websites like youtube, stackoverflow, chess.com, I can search for stuff on google, "
                  "I can open chrome, I can open VS Code, I can play music, I can even search for people's "
                  "information on wikipedia, and I can tell you the time. I am being developed, and many new features "
                  "are "
                  "yet to come...")

        # Fun questions
        elif 'hello' in command:
            speak("Hi Sir. How can I help you")

        elif 'how are you' in command:
            speak("I am really well sir. I am glad you asked")

        elif 'tell me a joke' in command:
            randomNumber = random.randint(1, 4)
            joke = linecache.getline("jokes.txt", randomNumber)
            speak(joke)
            print(joke)
            pygame.mixer.init()
            pygame.mixer.music.load("laughter.mp3")
            pygame.mixer.music.play()

        elif 'i am feeling bored' in command or 'entertain me' in command or "let's play a game" in command:
            speak("Sure, let's play Rock Paper Scissors Game!")
            while turns < 5:
                speak("Type a Number: 1 for Rock 2 for Paper and 3 for Scissor")
                rock_paper_or_scissor = int(input("Type a Number: 1 for Rock 2 for Paper "
                                                  "and 3 for Scissor"))

                botnumber = random.randrange(1, 4)
                # 1 = rock
                # 2 = paper
                # 3 = scissor
                if (rock_paper_or_scissor == 1 and botnumber == 1):
                    print("Computer played " + str(botnumber))
                    speak("Computer played " + str(botnumber))
                    print("You Played " + str(rock_paper_or_scissor))
                    speak("You Played " + str(rock_paper_or_scissor))
                    print("0 points")
                    speak("0 points")
                    turns += 1

                elif (rock_paper_or_scissor == 1 and botnumber == 2):
                    print("Computer played " + str(botnumber))
                    speak("Computer played " + str(botnumber))
                    print("You Played " + str(rock_paper_or_scissor))
                    speak("You Played " + str(rock_paper_or_scissor))
                    print("1 point to Computer")
                    speak("1 point to Computer")
                    botscore += 1
                    turns += 1

                elif (rock_paper_or_scissor == 1 and botnumber == 3):
                    print("Computer played " + str(botnumber))
                    speak("Computer played " + str(botnumber))
                    print("You Played " + str(rock_paper_or_scissor))
                    speak("You Played " + str(rock_paper_or_scissor))
                    print("1 point to you")
                    speak("1 point to you")
                    playerscore += 1
                    turns += 1

                elif (rock_paper_or_scissor == 2 and botnumber == 1):
                    print("Computer played " + str(botnumber))
                    speak("Computer played " + str(botnumber))
                    print("You Played " + str(rock_paper_or_scissor))
                    speak("You Played " + str(rock_paper_or_scissor))
                    print("1 point to you")
                    speak("1 point to you")
                    playerscore += 1
                    turns += 1

                elif (rock_paper_or_scissor == 2 and botnumber == 2):
                    print("Computer played " + str(botnumber))
                    speak("Computer played " + str(botnumber))
                    print("You Played " + str(rock_paper_or_scissor))
                    speak("You Played " + str(rock_paper_or_scissor))
                    print("Draw")
                    speak("Draw")
                    turns += 1

                elif (rock_paper_or_scissor == 2 and botnumber == 3):
                    print("Computer played " + str(botnumber))
                    speak("Computer played " + str(botnumber))
                    print("You Played " + str(rock_paper_or_scissor))
                    speak("You Played " + str(rock_paper_or_scissor))
                    print("1 point to Computer")
                    speak("1 point to Computer")
                    botscore += 1
                    turns += 1

                elif (rock_paper_or_scissor == 3 and botnumber == 1):
                    print("Computer played " + str(botnumber))
                    speak("Computer played " + str(botnumber))
                    print("You Played " + str(rock_paper_or_scissor))
                    speak("You Played " + str(rock_paper_or_scissor))
                    print("1 point to Computer")
                    speak("1 point to Computer")
                    botscore += 1
                    turns += 1

                elif (rock_paper_or_scissor == 3 and botnumber == 2):
                    print("Computer played " + str(botnumber))
                    speak("Computer played " + str(botnumber))
                    print("You Played " + str(rock_paper_or_scissor))
                    speak("You Played " + str(rock_paper_or_scissor))
                    print("1 point to you")
                    speak("1 point to you")
                    playerscore += 1
                    turns += 1

                elif (rock_paper_or_scissor == 3 and botnumber == 3):
                    print("Computer played " + str(botnumber))
                    speak("Computer played " + str(botnumber))
                    print("You Played " + str(rock_paper_or_scissor))
                    speak("You Played " + str(rock_paper_or_scissor))
                    print("Draw")
                    speak("Draw")
                    turns += 1

                elif (rock_paper_or_scissor > 3):
                    print("Error: Please enter a number less than or equal to 3 and greater than 0")
                    speak("Error: Please enter a number less than or equal to 3 and greater than 0")
                    turns -= 1

            print("-------------------------------------\nYour Score = " + str(playerscore))
            speak("Your Score = " + str(playerscore))
            print("Computer Score = " + str(botscore))
            speak("Computer Score = " + str(botscore))
            if playerscore == botscore:
                print("That's a Draw!")
                speak("That's a Draw!")
            elif playerscore > botscore:
                print("You WIN! Congratulations Sir!")
                speak("You WIN! Congratulations Sir!")
            elif playerscore < botscore:
                print("Computer WINS! Better luck next time")
                speak("Computer WINS! Better luck next time")

        elif 'thank you' in command:
            speak("My pleasure sir!")

        elif 'who created you' in command:
            speak("Sir, I was created by Sai Mishra")
            print("Sir, I was created by Sai Mishra")

        elif 'who made you' in command:
            speak("Sir, I was made by Sai Mishra")
            print("Sir, I was made by Sai Mishra")

        elif 'who is sahi mishra' in command:
            speak("Sir, Sai Mishra is a 13 year old YouTuber, programmer, web developer and an android developer")
            print("Sir, Sai Mishra is a 13 year old YouTuber, programmer, web developer and an android developer")

        elif 'when were you made' in command:
            speak("Sir, I was made on 31st August, in Bihar State of India, by Sai Mishra")
            print("Sir, I was made on 31st August, in Bihar State of India, by Sai Mishra")

        elif 'exit' in command:
            speak("Closing Program, bye sir!")
            curHour = int(datetime.datetime.now().hour)
            if 0 <= curHour < 16:
                speak("Have a nice day!")
                print("Have a nice day!")
            if 16 <= curHour < 20:
                speak("I hope I was helpful!")
                print("I hope I was helpful!")
            exit()

        elif 'take a note' in command or 'save a note' in command:
            speak("What note should I make?")
            userNote = userCommand()
            if userNote == "":
                speak("Cannot save a blank note")
            else:
                Writingfile = open("notes.txt", "a")
                Writingfile.write(userNote + "\n")
                Writingfile.close()
                speak("Done sir. Saved the note successfully. If you want to see your notes then say - 'Show me my "
                      "notes'")
                print("Done sir. Saved the note successfully. If you want to see your notes then say - 'Show me my "
                      "notes'")

        elif 'show me my notes' in command:
            print("Your note(s)")
            speak("Your notes")
            Readingfile = open("notes.txt", "r")
            print(Readingfile.read())
            speak(Readingfile.read())

        elif 'open youtube' in command:
            speak("Opening Youtube Sir...")
            # In python "Null" is called "None"
            webbrowser.register('chrome', None,
                                webbrowser.BackgroundBrowser
                                ("C://Program Files//Google\Chrome//Application//chrome.exe"))
            webbrowser.get('chrome').open("youtube.com")

        elif 'open stack overflow' in command:
            speak("Opening Stackoverflow...")
            webbrowser.register('chrome', None,
                                webbrowser.BackgroundBrowser
                                ("C://Program Files//Google\Chrome//Application//chrome.exe"))
            webbrowser.get('chrome').open("stackoverflow.com")

        elif 'open chess' in command:
            speak("Opening Chess.com...")
            webbrowser.register('chrome', None,
                                webbrowser.BackgroundBrowser
                                ("C://Program Files//Google\Chrome//Application//chrome.exe"))
            webbrowser.get('chrome').open("chess.com")

        elif 'open gmail' in command:
            speak("Opening Gmail...")
            webbrowser.register('chrome', None,
                                webbrowser.BackgroundBrowser
                                ("C://Program Files//Google\Chrome//Application//chrome.exe"))
            webbrowser.get('chrome').open("https://mail.google.com/mail/u/1/#inbox")

        elif 'show me my mails' in command:
            speak("Opening Gmail...")
            webbrowser.register('chrome', None,
                                webbrowser.BackgroundBrowser
                                ("C://Program Files//Google\Chrome//Application//chrome.exe"))
            webbrowser.get('chrome').open("https://mail.google.com/mail/u/1/#inbox")

        elif 'what are my new mails' in command:
            speak("Opening Gmail...")
            webbrowser.register('chrome', None,
                                webbrowser.BackgroundBrowser
                                ("C://Program Files//Google\Chrome//Application//chrome.exe"))
            webbrowser.get('chrome').open("https://mail.google.com/mail/u/1/#inbox")

        elif 'open remove.bg' in command:
            speak("Opening Remove.bg...")
            webbrowser.register('chrome', None,
                                webbrowser.BackgroundBrowser
                                ("C://Program Files//Google\Chrome//Application//chrome.exe"))
            webbrowser.get('chrome').open("https://www.remove.bg/")

        elif 'play music' in command:
            speak("Playing Music...")
            music_path = 'C:\\Users\\shiva\\Desktop\\Favorite songs'
            songs = os.listdir(music_path)
            os.startfile(os.path.join(music_path, songs[0]))

        elif 'sing a song' in command:
            speak("Twinkle Twinkle Little star, how I wonder what you are. Up above the world so high. Like a diamond "
                  "in the sky.")
            speak("I know I sang really bad, can you please ask me something else?")

        elif 'the time' in command:
            # Getting time in hours and minutes
            timeStr = datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%H:%M")
            print("The current time is " + timeStr)
            speak("The current time is " + timeStr)

        elif 'open vs code' in command:
            speak("Opening Visual Studio Code")
            vscPath = "C:\\Users\\shiva\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Microsoft VS Code\\Code.exe"
            os.startfile(vscPath)

        elif 'open chrome' in command:
            speak("Opening Google Chrome")
            chromePath = "C:\\Program Files\\Google\\Chrome\\Application\\chrome.exe"
            os.startfile(chromePath)

        elif 'open photoshop' in command:
            speak("Opening Adobe Photoshop")
            photoshopPath = "C:\\Program Files\\Adobe\\Adobe Photoshop 2021\\Photoshop.exe"
            os.startfile(photoshopPath)

        elif 'open important' in command:
            speak("Opening Important Tutorials Folder")
            imptutPath = "C:\\Users\\shiva\\Desktop\\Coding\\Important Tutorials"
            os.startfile(imptutPath)

        elif 'search' in command:
            speak("What should I search")
            searchContent = userCommand()
            speak("Searching Google...")
            webbrowser.register('chrome', None,
                                webbrowser.BackgroundBrowser
                                ("C://Program Files//Google\Chrome//Application//chrome.exe"))
            webbrowser.get('chrome').open("https://www.google.com/search?q=" + searchContent +
                                          "&oq=wht&aqs=chrome..69i57j0i10l3j0i10i433l3j0i10j0i10i433l2."
                                          "1465j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8")


        else:
            speak("Sorry sir, I can't do that currently")
```

I first installed the SpeechRecognition module using 'pip install SpeechRecognition'
I had already made a project like this in the past and didn't face any issue. Can anyone tell me what's wrong?

Comment: Make sure you aren't using any virtual environment. Also, can you show us the error you got as a screenshot

Comment: @codester_09 why a screenshot? It should be text pasted into the original post.

Comment: @blackbrandt Nah I want to make sure OP isn't using a virtual environment. Text-based only show the module not found error.

Comment: Could you add output of `pip list`?

Comment: It is working, I changed the interpreter and it is working fine now

Answer (score 1):

Try checking if the python version you're using to run the script is the same you installed the module for.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect one of two issues here, so we need to tackle them separately:

1. You are using a `venv` or other virtual environment, and the `SpeechRecognition` module is not loaded in that environment, as the comments suggest.
2. Or, installing the `SpeechRecognition` module with `pip install SpeechRecognition` has failed in some way. This module has several dependencies. So, could you please provide the output of `python -m speech_recognition` - as the docs suggest - to prove that the package has been installed correctly?

Comment: I tried to run 'python -m speech_recognition' on the terminal, and its working. (It instructed me to say something)

Comment: Thanks for confirming @SaiMishra. This points to an issue with your environment. Do you have a virtual environment such as `venv` or `conda` set up in your project? If so, was the virtual environment activated (for example with a command like `source bin/activate`) when you ran the `python -m speech_recognition` command?

Comment: @SaiMishra could you also please paste the _exact_ error message you receive? This will help debug the issue.